# Akka Stream TLS Server Logging & Troubleshooting

Tags: scala, ssl, openssl, akka, akka-stream

I'm using Akka Streams to create a TCP server using akka.stream.scaladsl.TLS with client certificate authentication. I'm working on creating an echo server as a first proof of concept.

In the meantime, I'm new to Scala/Akka/Akka Streams and so I created a similar server and TCP client in Python to provide tooling in testing my work in Scala. The Python server/client are functional using client cert authentication. When connecting to the server, the client takes the following steps:

- Creates and configures an SSLContext
- Creates a socket using socket.create_connection()
- Wraps the socket with the SSLContext using SSLContext.wrap_socket(). This creates the peer connection
- Once connected, prints the server certificate
- Infinite loop asking for input and sending each input to the server

I believe I have the server completed using Akka Streams and akka.stream.scaladsl.TLS, but when I attempt to connect using my Python client the client never gets past connecting to the peer using `context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=host)`. The server successfully binds the TCP connection and creates the corresponding IncomingConnection object. The client/server also never timeout (the client just sits awaiting the handshake?).

My biggest problem is that I see no information from my TLS BidiFlow, akka.stream.scaladsl.TLS. I have no idea what step in the handshake I'm stuck at, which makes troubleshooting very difficult.

**Is there any way to output some information throughout the TLS handshake process? It seems as though all of the functionality is encapsulated and I don't know if there's any way to troubleshoot.**

Otherwise, I'm attempting to troubleshoot with openssl and get the following:

```
bash$ openssl s_client -connect myserver.com:443 -state -debug
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
write to 0x7fd914100080 [0x7fd915001000] (318 bytes => 318 (0x13E))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 39 01 00 01-35 03 03 e3 ff 5d fb 26   ....9...5....].&
0010 - 15 e3 32 89 37 e2 cb 95-f5 00 bd df 13 3d ae a6   ..2.7........=..
0020 - d7 37 db 4e 80 19 63 ad-d6 6c f1 00 00 98 cc 14   .7.N..c..l......
0030 - cc 13 cc 15 c0 30 c0 2c-c0 28 c0 24 c0 14 c0 0a   .....0.,.(.$....
0040 - 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a-00 39 00 38 ff 85 00 c4   .....k.j.9.8....
0050 - 00 c3 00 88 00 87 00 81-c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a c0 26   .........2...*.&
0060 - c0 0f c0 05 00 9d 00 3d-00 35 00 c0 00 84 c0 2f   .......=.5...../
0070 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a2 00 9e 00 67   .+.'.#.........g
0080 - 00 40 00 33 00 32 00 be-00 bd 00 45 00 44 c0 31   .@.3.2.....E.D.1
0090 - c0 2d c0 29 c0 25 c0 0e-c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f   .-.).%.......<./
00a0 - 00 ba 00 41 c0 11 c0 07-c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00 04   ...A............
00b0 - c0 12 c0 08 00 16 00 13-c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 15   ................
00c0 - 00 12 00 09 00 ff 01 00-00 74 00 0b 00 04 03 00   .........t......
00d0 - 01 02 00 0a 00 3a 00 38-00 0e 00 0d 00 19 00 1c   .....:.8........
00e0 - 00 0b 00 0c 00 1b 00 18-00 09 00 0a 00 1a 00 16   ................
00f0 - 00 17 00 08 00 06 00 07-00 14 00 15 00 04 00 05   ................
0100 - 00 12 00 13 00 01 00 02-00 03 00 0f 00 10 00 11   ................
0110 - 00 23 00 00 00 0d 00 26-00 24 06 01 06 02 06 03   .#.....&.$......
0120 - ef ef 05 01 05 02 05 03-04 01 04 02 04 03 ee ee   ................
0130 - ed ed 03 01 03 02 03 03-02 01 02 02 02 03         ..............
SSL_connect:unknown state
```

At which point openssl just hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I found that the ssl-config logging is very sparse and wasn't helpful to resolving my issue. It does provide some debugging information but not much. Much better for debugging the TLS handshake is to use the `-Djavax.net.debug=all` flag when running the JVM. However, even this provides mixed results. For example, the resulting error I received is that the server couldn't find a matching cipher suite. Eventually I resolved my issue by realizing that when creating the input streams for my keystore/truststore I was specifying my path incorrectly.

Note for anyone coming across this: if you specify your keystore and truststore incorrectly the resulting input streams will be null and SSLContext.init will happily use these and provide an error that is unrelated to the keystore/truststore! This was very difficult to troubleshoot due to the incorrect error handling in SSLContext.

Answer (score 0):

The Akka TLS support uses the built in Java TLS support behind the scenes, so to get debug output for TLS you'll have to enable debugging for that. It can be done through passing a system property to the JVM when starting it like so `-Djavax.net.debug=all`